# circle inside hollow circle on :before

Tags: html, css, styles

I need your help very much :) I am bad in css very much, I need have two classes one for links and one for active-links. Link class must be a hollow circle I got this:

```
  &:before {
    content: '';
    margin-right: 0.75rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: -50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0.3rem solid #ffffff;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
  }
```

but how to achive the active result? Circle inside hallow circle? on one pseudo element? Thank you very much for any suggestion :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use radial gradient in css

Remove border and use this line in :before

```
background:radial-gradient( white 20% , rgb(6, 42, 64) 21% , rgb(6, 42, 64) 47% , white 48% );
```

Check also the example below, the container is not used for anything other than having a different background everything is applied on :before

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:#062a40;
}

.container:before
  {
    content:" ";
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    border-radius:50%;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient( white 20% , rgb(6, 42, 64) 21% , rgb(6, 42, 64) 47% , white 48% );
    background: -o-radial-gradient( white 20% , rgb(6, 42, 64) 21% , rgb(6, 42, 64) 47% , white 48% );
    background: -moz-radial-gradient( white 20% , rgb(6, 42, 64) 21% , rgb(6, 42, 64) 47% , white 48% );
    background: radial-gradient( white 20% , rgb(6, 42, 64) 21% , rgb(6, 42, 64) 47% , white 48% );
  }
```

You can customize it by changing radial gradient colors percentages, also don't forget to add browser prefixes